# Generators for the first cohomology of free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, free-groups, group-rings

Let $F = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle$ be the free group on $n$ generators and $R = \mathbb Z$. The Fox derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \colon F \to R[F]$ are the unique derivations satisfying $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_j) = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}$, where $R[F]$ is the group ring. Since they represent non-trivial elements in $\mathrm{H}^1(F; R[F])$ i am curious if $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \}$ is a generating set for $\mathrm{H}^1(F; R[F])$ as an $R[F]$-module?

When $n = 1$ one can compute that $\mathrm{H}^1(F; R[F]) \cong R$ (as an $R[t^{\pm 1}]$-module), but how can i show something is a generator?
For $n > 2$ i don't even know how to compute "the isomorphism type" of $\mathrm{H}^1(F; R[F])$ (from a suitable resolution one can see that it is at most generated by $n$ elements)...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are a generating set.  In fact, even more is true.  Recall that for a group $G$ and a $G$-module $M$, the first cohomology group $H^1(G;M)$ is the abelian group $Der(G,M)$ of derivations $G \rightarrow M$ modulo the principal derivations.  The group $Der(F;R[F])$ of derivations from $F$ to $R[F]$ forms a right $R[F]$-module (the point being that $R[F]$ has both a left action used to define derivations and a (commuting) right action).  We then have that $Der(F,R[F])$ is a free right $R[F]$-module with basis the free derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

To see this, consider a derivation $f\colon F \rightarrow R[F]$.  For $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $u_i = f(x_i)$.  Using the right $R[F]$-module structure on derivations, let $f'\colon F \rightarrow R[F]$ be the derivation
$$f'(w) = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_1} u_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_n} u_n \quad \text{for $w \in F$}.$$
Then $f(x_i) = f'(x_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, which implies that $f = f'$.  Since the $u_i$ that make this work are uniquely defined, this implies what we want.